# Convert rows into columns using awk

Tags: awk, sed

Not all columns (&data) are present for all records. Hence whenever fields missing are missing, they should be replaced with nulls.

**My Input format:**

```
    .set 1000  
EMP_NAME="Rob"  
EMP_DES="Developer"  
EMP_DEP="Sales"  
EMP_DOJ="20-10-2010"  
EMR_MGR="Jack"      
     .set 1001  
EMP_NAME="Koster"  
EMP_DEP="Promotions"  
EMP_DOJ="20-10-2011"      
    .set 1002  
EMP_NAME="Boua"  
EMP_DES="TA"  
EMR_MGR="James"
```

**My desired output Format:**

```
Rob~Developer~Sales~20-10-2010~Jack  
Koster~~Promotions~20-10-2011~  
Boua~TA~~~James
```

**I tried the below:**

```
awk 'NR>1{printf "%s"(/^\.set/?RS:"~"),a} {a=substr($0,index($0,"=")+1)} END {print a}' $line
```

**This is printing:**

```
Rob~Developer~Sales~20-10-2010~Jack  
Koster~Promotions~20-10-2011~  
Boua~TA~James~
```

Comment: Where are the rows? It looks like everything is on the same line.

Comment: @Ed it looks like each field is separated by a `~` in the output, so when a field is missing there are two adjacent `~`. I believe my script produces what the OP is looking for.

Answer (score 0):

This awk script produces the desired output:

```
BEGIN { FS = "[=\"]+"; OFS = "~" }

/\.set/ { ++records; next }

NR > 1 { f[records,$1] = $2 }

END {    
    for (i = 1; i <= records; ++i) {
        print f[i,"EMP_NAME"], f[i,"EMP_DES"], f[i,"EMP_DEP"], f[i,"EMP_DOJ"], f[i,"EMR_MGR"]
    }
}
```

A two-dimensional array is used to store all of the values that are defined for each record.

After all the file has been processed, the loop goes through each row of the array and prints all of the values. The elements that are undefined will be evaluated as an empty string.

Specifying the elements explicity allows you to control the order in which they are printed. Using `print` rather than `printf` allows you to make correct use of the `OFS` variable which has been set to `~`, as well as the `ORS` which is a newline character by default.

Thanks to @Ed for [his helpful comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24869142/convert-rows-into-columns-using-awk/24869920#comment38627274_24869920) that pointed out some flaws in my original script.

Output:

```
Rob~Developer~Sales~20-10-2010~Jack
Koster~~Promotions~20-10-2011~
Boua~TA~~~James
```

Comment: You should mention its' gawk-specific due to the multi-char RS. Also, `RS=".set"` means that if you have `EMP_NAME="Lisette"` in your input file, that will result in a record terminating at `EMP_NAME="L` and another starting at `te` since the middle part of her name, `iset`, matches the RE `.set`.

Answer (score 0):

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN{ FS="[=\"]+"; OFS="~" }
/\.set/ { ++numRecs; next }
{ name2val[numRecs,$1] = $2 }
!seen[$1]++ { names[++numNames] = $1 }
END {
    for (recNr=1; recNr<=numRecs; recNr++)
        for (nameNr=1; nameNr<=numNames; nameNr++)
            printf "%s%s", name2val[recNr,names[nameNr]], (nameNr<numNames?OFS:ORS)
}

$ awk -f tst.awk file
Rob~Developer~Sales~20-10-2010~Jack
Koster~~Promotions~20-10-2011~
Boua~TA~~~James
```

If you want some pre-defined order of fields in your output rather than creating it on the fly from the rows in each record as they're read, just populate the `names[]` array explicitly in the BEGIN section and if you have that situation AND don't want to save the whole file in memory:

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN{
    FS="[=\"]+"; OFS="~";
    numNames=split("EMP_NAME EMP_DES EMP_DEP EMP_DOJ EMR_MGR",names,/ /)
}
function prtName2val(   nameNr, i) {
    if ( length(name2val) ) {
        for (nameNr=1; nameNr<=numNames; nameNr++)
            printf "%s%s", name2val[names[nameNr]], (nameNr<numNames?OFS:ORS)
        delete name2val
    }
}
/\.set/ { prtName2val(); next }
{ name2val[$1] = $2 }
END { prtName2val() }

$ awk -f tst.awk file
Rob~Developer~Sales~20-10-2010~Jack
Koster~~Promotions~20-10-2011~
Boua~TA~~~James
```

The above uses GNU awk for `length(name2val)` and `delete name2val`, if you don't have that then use `for (i in name2val) { do stuff; break }` and `split("",name2val)` instead..

Comment: There is a syntax error in your script; I think you may have missed something off when copying in your code.

Comment: Yeah, I posted it then realized I didn't need parens in one area and removed one of the pair but not the other. fixed now, thx.

Answer (score -1):

This is all I can suggest:

```
awk '{ t = $0; sub(/^[^"]*"/, "", t); gsub(/"[^"]*"/, "~", t); sub(/".*/, "", t); print t }' file
```

Or sed:

```
sed -re 's|^[^"]*"||; s|"[^"]*"|~|g; s|".*||' file
```

Output:

```
Rob~Developer~Sales~20-10-2010~Jack~Koster~Promotions~20-10-2011~Boua~TA~James
```